# Can't write > and < symbols with my Pok3r keyboard, how do I rebind my keys/shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

As the title says, I'd love to rebind my keyboard to be able to write < by pressing: "right alt + ," and > by pressing "right alt + ." on my Pok3r keyboard. I'm using a Swedish layout which makes those key's impossible to access with my 60% key keyboard.

Could you guys help me out? I'm running Ubuntu 17.10. My keyboard is an ANSI one.

Thanks!